# When I switch between actions my armature changes location

Tags: actions

I just made a walk cycle with an armature and when I simply move from the walk cycle action to another action the armature changes location. Here's the first
screen capture before I switch actions.

[image: armature before switching actions]

Here's what happens when I switch actions

[image: armature after switching actions]

I should say that when I imported this armature the bone connections where messed up. In fact I couldn't find them, just sticks and circles. But I did my
best to make a great looking walk cycle. Tried changing the armature location and adding new LocRotScale info to each keyframe but that didn't fix the problem.

Comment: it must happen because the armature object itself must have been keyframed and this animation must be part of the action you select. If it's the case you can see that in your Dopesheet, on the bottom of the bones tracks, there's a track called LocRotScale and it's the one for the object itself, if you delete all the keyframes of this track it may fix the problem.

Comment: That armature has about 100 different sections. I just can delete each locrotscale of each section.

Comment: I fixed it. What I did was change the cursor location to be under the armature and then I changed the armature's origin to the cursor location

Comment: ok, not sure what was your problem but if you fixed it...  ;)